# How do I properly stack col elements on small screens in 1 row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When using the built in bootstrap col classes, when I shrink my grid to mobile , the columns are taking 100% of the width of the row thus on mobile this results in a very long vertical list of items even though there should be space on the horizontal axis to accommodate for more items.

This is for a personal website I'm doing, it's a course section where I'm laying out a grid of the courses we would like to offer.  The problem and what I've already tried is explained below.

This is the HTML I have:

```
  <div class="container courses-container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center courses-header no-gutters">
          <div class="col-1">
            <h2>Courses</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row courses">
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <div >
              <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid"  >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row courses">
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">
            <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musical-instruments-22/50/22-512.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" height="210px" width="200px" >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
.courses-header {
    margin: 2em 0;
}

.carousel-container, .courses-container {
  padding: 0;
}

@media (min-width:  720px) {
  .courses {
  margin: 3em 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .course-item {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

The last media query at the 767px breakpoint 'fixes' the issue by targeting the custom class **i've set to each column so that I make them take up only 33% of the width on smaller screens, however if you comment out that section and preview this example on a smaller screen you'll see that each column will essentially sit on one line**. This is why I've also set col-xs-1 on each item but I think I don't need it if I use another approach.

Is this the right way to do it because to me it seems like that there should be an easier way in which I can control the grid to be displayed properly on smaller screens.

The full layout on larger screens is taking 2 rows and each row has 6 columns in it. On smaller screens this layout is not possible since it's too wide.

I expect once I resize the browser window to a smaller one that the cols will break in to more rows vertically and they do but without adjusting their width with a media query each column  breaks in to its own line taking 100% of it thus it creates alot of veritical space and it doesn't use the horizontal space properly as there's a lot of it left empty.

Ideally it should smoothly break the items in to more rows but keeping several columns on each line, the smaller the screen the less items on each line but at all times it should keep at least 2 , if not 3 items side by side.

Comment: There is no `col-xs-*` .. it's just `col-*` now in Bootstrap 4 so you would use `col-1` not `col-xs-1`.

Comment: @zim thank you, I think that fixes some of the issues I've experienced, repalcing my existing `col-xs-*` classes with `col-2` looks better but now it essentially just 'shrinks' the large screen layout to a smaller screen. I'm wondering if there's a way to have it have more rows once you go to a smaller size. Essentially on a smaller screen if I had 3 rows or 4 rows and then split the columns evenly on them it would look better but the only way I know how to do that is to write extra html and conditionally display it with a media query. (i.e have different html for smaller screens)

Comment: Just to clarify - are you saying you want the end result to be multiple rows on a small screen, - say 3-4 columns per row, and on a large screen you want these to expand out to the layout you have now (two rows)?
Currently, the reason the desktop format simply shrinks on a mobile and not rearrange the size of the columns is because you haven't included this line in the <head> of your html: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: Also get rid of the col-1 classes --- replace them with col-3 for example. That way you will have 4 items per row

Comment: @Jonny I do have the meta tag in my document, I just didn't copy it over in the example. What did it for me is the col-4 (or col-3 as you suggested but I find that col-4 works better) and then on medium and upwards devices having col-md-2 so that the 2rows I have defined now are followed on larger devices. Thanks for the help! Now I do have problems with the header text not being centered on smaller screens for some reason which I still haven't figured out why but if I can't solve it I'll probably open a new question.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Regarding your header issue.... you can use an offset class available in Bootstrap: on small screens if you give your header the class *col-xs-8* for example, and also add the class *offset-xs-2*, then bearing in mind that Bootstrap uses a 12 col grid, this will make your header 8 col wide, with a two col margin on the left, therefore making it centred.

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-xs-2` on all `<div class="col-xs-1 col-md-2 course-item">`

Remove `col-xs-1` and add `col-xs-2`